# Можно ли в Wordpress изменить header для одной конкретной страницы для вывода на ней изображения из базы данных?

Tags: php, wordpress

Сохраняю изображения в базе данных MySQL в пользовательской таблице Wordpress в формате Blob.
Затем вывожу их в самописном плагине, который через шорткод подключается в определенной странице. Но для вывода из базы данных изображения в таком виде, нужно, чтобы выли установлены header("content-type:image/jpeg"); А так вместо изображения выводятся квакозябры.
Можно ли для этой страницы установить header?

Comment: Изображения в БД, заголовки страниц-изображений.. ОМГ... А по человечески почему не делать?

Comment: Как? В файловой системе сохранять?

Comment: Как это делают все нормальные люди и ВП по умолчанию. Естественно, файлами. Более того все загружаемые картинки должны хранится в медиатеке (это уже правильные записи в базе).

Comment: @kuchuluk обычно в БД хранится путь к изображению, а не само изображение (это касается не только WordPress), так как хранение изображения непосредственно в БД имеет ряд недостатков.

Comment: Наверное будет иметь смысл более конкретно описать Вашу задачу и почему именно Вы решили что хранить изображение в БД Вам необходимо, отталкиваясь от этого уже можно будет что-то посоветовать, так как скорее всего есть другие способы решения Вашей задачи.